# SharpDX.DXGI - DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL

Tags: exception, directx-11, sharpdx

I've searched for the solution a lot, but i can't find it.
Here is my code:

```
namespace MySharpDXGame
{
 public class Game
 {

    public static void Main()
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.InitializeGraphics();
        RenderLoop.Run(game.MainForm, game.RenderCallback);
    }

    private RenderForm MainForm;

    private const int Width = 1280;
    private const int Height = 720;

    private D11.Device device;
    private D11.DeviceContext context;
    private SwapChain chain;

    private D11.RenderTargetView rendtargview;

    public Game()
    {
        MainForm = new RenderForm("Simple Render")
        {
            ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height),
            AllowUserResizing = true  
        };

    }

    private void RenderCallback()
    {
        Draw();
    }

    public void InitializeGraphics()
    {
        ModeDescription modesc = new ModeDescription(Width, Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm);
        SwapChainDescription chaindesk = new SwapChainDescription()
        {
            ModeDescription = modesc,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
            BufferCount = 1,
            OutputHandle = MainForm.Handle,
            IsWindowed = true
        };

        D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, D11.DeviceCreationFlags.None, chaindesk, out device, out chain);
        context = device.ImmediateContext;
        rendtargview = new D11.RenderTargetView(device, chain.GetBackBuffer<D11.Texture2D>(0));
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("created!");
    }

    private void Draw()
    {
        context.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(rendtargview);
        context.ClearRenderTargetView(rendtargview, new Scolor(32, 103, 178, 255));
    }
}
}
```

The exception is thrown at line

```
D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, D11.DeviceCreationFlags.None, chaindesk, out device, out chain);
```

I've installed DirectX SDK June 2010. My computer runs on Windows 7 SP1. I am doing this project in Visual Studio Community 2017. SharpDX libraries was downloaded from NuGet.
Here is the full log of exception:

```
SharpDX.SharpDXException: "HRESULT: [0x887A0001], Module: [SharpDX.DXGI], ApiCode: [DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL/InvalidCall], Message: Unknown"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Debug DeviceCreationFlags. This should help you to locate the problem. Also i can only recommend the sharpdx tutorials from robydx:

[Tutorials](https://github.com/RobyDX/SharpDX_Demo/tree/master/SharpDXTutorial)